# Sort an ArrayList of object by title property

Tags: java, oop, sorting, arraylist

I have an objects class that holds the properties title, director, genre, rating. I have created an arraylist and have filled it with instances of this base class

```
ArrayList<Movie> movieCatalog
```

I am wanting to sort this ArrayList in alphabetical order by the title property and change their positions within the ArrayList. From my research I understand I need to use a Comparator class but I am confused about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom comparator and than call the `Collections.sort(movieCatalog,comparator);` method.

E.g.

```
public static final Comparator<movieCatalog> movieComparator = new Comparator<movieCatalog>() {
        public int compare(movieCatalog a1, movieCatalog a2) {
            return a1.name.compareTo(a2.name);
        }
    };


Collections.sort(movieCatakig,movieComparator);
```

Comment: But how would I change the positions of the objects within the ArrayList

Comment: When you call `Collection.sort`, and put the movieCatalog, and movieComparator, the arraylist is sorted for you. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help unlike some other on this forum

Comment: Adding a custom comparator for such a simple case sounds like overkill. Implementing a compareto() method (like in the other answer below) sounds more sensible in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

Your `Movie` class needs to implement `Comparable<Movie>`. Then you need to implement the `compareTo` method, which in this case can just call the String class `compareTo` method.

```
int compareTo(Movie other) {
    return this.title.compareTo(other.title);
}
```

After that, if `movies` is an ArrayList of movies, you can simply do

```
Collections.sort(movies);
```